# Compiling C++ error with unidentified symbols for x86_x64 architecture

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

While I study C++ in mac os, I wrote a code complied. But my command console throws out error like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Circle::Circle(int, int)", referenced from:
      _main in basic-WAP6oS.o
  "Circle::~Circle()", referenced from:
      _main in basic-WAP6oS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and here is my code:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 
  4 class Shape {
  5     public:
  6         Shape (int new_origin); // constructor
  7         ~Shape (); // distructor
  8         virtual void draw () = 0; // NULL virtual point
  9     private:
 10         int origin;
 11 };
 12 
 13 class Circle : public Shape { // inherit Shape class
 14     public:
 15         Circle (int new_origin, int new_radius);
 16         ~Circle ();
 17         virtual void draw ();
 18     private:
 19         int radius, area;
 20 };
 21 
 22 int main() {
 23 
 24     int origin = 10;
 25     int of_no_return = 0;
 26 
 27     Circle letter(origin, 100);
 28     return 0;
 29 }
```

I compiled this `basic.cpp` source with g++ command. That is:

```
g++ -o basic basic.cpp
```

I just guess that error is occurred because of referencing complier. But I can not sure. Will you give me some advice and explanation of error message, which `referenced from: _main in` part? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your shape destructor should be virtual!

Comment: Your code does not have definitions for the symbols stated in the error messages. There are only declarations.

Comment: I got that! I forgot to declare all of class' attribution. appreciate @IInspectable!